# Priemfaces p:commandButton con ui:repeat solo funciona un solo boton

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema, estoy utilizando primefaces para mi front y en una sección estoy utilizando el ui:repeat de JSF para generar dinamicamente una vista de grillas donde cada grilla muestras un banco y sus saldo segun distintas condicones, ahora el codigo repeat cumple perfectamente su función y me genera perfectamente mi grilla de banco con sus distintos saldos, sin embargo al probrar el boton de "Ver movimientos" solo me funciona el primer recuadro los demas no hacen nada ni marca error la consola.

Dejo el codigo aqui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="recursos/CSS_Inicio.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="recursos/CSS_General.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="recursos/CSS_Medidas.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<div>
    <h:form>
        <p:menubar model="#{menu.model}"/>
    </h:form>
</div>

<div>
    <h:form prependId="false" id="visor_bancos">
        <div class="Contenerdo_Banco" >
            <ui:repeat var="ban" value="#{inicio.lista_Bancos}">
                <div class="Banco">
                    <div class="Banco_Titulo">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{ban.banco}" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="Visor_Saldos Margin_top_05">
                        <div class="Margin_top_05">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Saldo" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{inicio.saldo_conciliado(ban.id_banco)}" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="Margin_top_05">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Asignación sin conciliar" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{inicio.montos_sin_conciliar(ban.id_banco, 'ASIGNACION')}" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="Margin_top_05">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Deducción sin conciliar" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="Margin_bottom_05">
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{inicio.montos_sin_conciliar(ban.id_banco, 'DEDUCCION')}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <h:form>
                            <p:commandButton class="Banco_Botones Margin_top_05" 
                                            value="Ver movimientos#{ban.id_banco}" 
                                            action="#{movimientos.cargar_lista_movimientos(ban.id_banco)}"/>
                            <p:commandButton class="Banco_Botones Margin_top_05" value="Eliminar banco" />
                        </h:form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ui:repeat>
            <p:commandButton value="Agregar&#10;Banco" onclick="PF('banco_Nuevo').show();" class="Banco_Agregar_Boton"/>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</div>

<!--VENTANAS EMERGENTES (MODALES)-->
<p:dialog widgetVar="banco_Nuevo" modal="true" >
    <ui:include src="/Bancos/nuevo_banco.xhtml"/>
</p:dialog>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad David, podrías poner el código así podemos ayudarte

Comment: No se que paso que no mostraba el codigo pero hay tienen

Comment: Para mí sería mejor que utilizaras el control p:dataTable de PrimeFaces.

Comment: El data table no cumpla con lo que quiero mostrar. Imaginate lo siguiente: si miras tu pad numerico del 1 al 9, veras que cada numero es una tecla necesito que cada banco sea una tecla la cual cada una muestra datos basicos y si lo quiero ver sus movimientos esta el boton que me esta dando problema. Bueno el primer boton funciona bien los demas no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya resolvi el problema, he eliminado las etiquetas del  que agrupaba los commandButton y funcina bien ahora.

```
               <div>
                    <h:form>
                        <p:commandButton class="Banco_Botones Margin_top_05" 
                                        value="Ver movimientos#{ban.id_banco}" 
                                        action="#{movimientos.cargar_lista_movimientos(ban.id_banco)}"/>
                        <p:commandButton class="Banco_Botones Margin_top_05" value="Eliminar banco" />
                    </h:form>
                </div>
```

Ahora el codigo quedo haci

```
                        <div>
                        <p:commandButton class="Banco_Botones Margin_top_05" 
                                        value="Ver movimientos#{ban.id_Banco}" 
                                        action="#{movimientos.ir_A_Movimientos(ban.id_Banco)}"/>
                        <p:commandButton class="Banco_Botones Margin_top_05" value="Eliminar banco" />
                    </div>
```